# Keep Session in Sync with FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, security, session, authentication, forms-authentication

When a user logs in through my login page, I authenticate them using FormsAuthentication, and set some Sessions that holds user specific info, like UserID and RoleID. I set site content based on these values.

The problem is when the session expires and the user is still signed in - things are messed up, because the session is null but the user is still signed in.

How can I keep them in sync with each other, so the session only expires if they're signed out or vs.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered storing the user ID and roles in the forms authentication cookie itself? That's the [common practice](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311495/how-to-implement-role-based-security-with-forms-based-authentication-i).

Answer (score 0):

When the session has ended (Session_OnEnd) in global.asax, you can kill the forms authentication cookie.  Doing so will redirect the user to the default page (or login page depending on how you set it up) upon any subsequent requests.  You should also kill the authentication cookie when user has manually logged out - same effect.

To kill the authentication cookie:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: I get a null exception when I do that in Session_End event.

Comment: Are you getting a null exception on the session?

Comment: Getting the exception on the FormsAuthentication.SignOut() method. (understandably - a quick google search explains it)